# liquibase :: is it possible to remove <validCheckSum> tags programmatically

Tags: liquibase

In Liquibase, the incrementby attribute in addautoincrement tag throws validation error in 4.16.1 version. I had to remove the incrementby attribute, which changed the md5sum.
To tackle that I had added `<validCheckSum>1:any</validCheckSum>` for now.

I plan to delete the md5sum and let it populate in all the environments by itself.
How can I remove the  `<validCheckSum>1:any</validCheckSum>` tags programmatically once it is no longer required?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on the Liquibase forum:

- [IncrementBy does not work for MySQL in Liquibase 4.17](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/incrementby-does-not-work-for-mysql-in-liquibase-4-17/7454/2)

The solution on that post says:

> We’ve solved the problem by replacing the `<addAutoIncrement>` by sql-statements:

```
<addAutoIncrement tableName=“Actief” columnName=“id” columnDataType=“BIGINT” incrementBy=“1” startWith=“1”/>

    <sql>ALTER TABLE Actief MODIFY id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT</sql>
    <sql>ALTER TABLE Actief AUTO_INCREMENT=1</sql>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the tag when it is not longer required - wouldnt you just remove the line

```
<validCheckSum>1:any</validCheckSum>
```

and do a new release?

Anyway - I think that is not a good idea to remove the checksum.

It gives you a pretty good security, that the script ran correctly and no changes will be accepted after it has run once.

Otherwise everyone could change those scripts and rerun them all over again - you lose a lot of trackability.

Ideally, you should test your liquibase scripts on a test database and revert them here if they aren't good. But once its good, you should commit it and let your pipeline execute the migration script when deploying your environment.

If you want to correct something afterwards, you should do a new liquibase script.

It is what I would recommend atleast, for the sake of data integrity and trackability of changes to the database.